# Using local parameter with the same name of a special one within a function

Tags: parameters, zsh

As I like to use descriptive parameter names, I often tried to use variable names already used by Zsh itself.

As it took me into trouble in the past, I now wrap my script in a *main* function named after the script. Then I declare all my local parameter using the `local` keyword.

But some parameters seems to not allow hiding them in the local scope:

```sh
function foo
{
    local commands=(bar baz)
    local status=0

    echo ${(F)commands}
    echo $status
}
```

Here, the local `commands` parameter is used in place of the special one.

But as the `status` parameter is read-only, I got the following error:

> zdm:6: read-only variable: status

I think that the `local` keyword allow to use a special parameter in a local scope but it does not change the way it was declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a special parameter name within a local scope, you have to **hide it explicitly** using the `-h` flag of the `typeset` builtin:

```sh
typeset -h status
```

As you want to declare it as local, use the `local` keyword which also supports that flag:

```sh
local -h status
```

You can also use the `private` keyword from the `zsh/param/private` module:

```sh
zmodload zsh/param/private

private -h status
```

### The `-h` flag

From the Zsh manual:

> `-h`
>
> Hide: only useful for special parameters (those marked `<S>` in the table in Parameters Set By The Shell), and for local parameters with the same name as a special parameter, though harmless for others.
>
> **A special parameter with this attribute will not retain its special effect when made local**. Thus after `typeset -h PATH`, a function containing `typeset PATH` will create an ordinary local parameter without the usual behaviour of PATH.
>
> Alternatively, **the local parameter may itself be given this attribute**; hence inside a function `typeset -h PATH` creates an ordinary local parameter and the special PATH parameter is not altered in any way.
>
> It is also possible to create a local parameter using `typeset +h special`, where the local copy of special will retain its special properties regardless of having the -h attribute.
>
> Global special parameters loaded from shell modules (currently those in zsh/mapfile and zsh/parameter) are automatically given the `-h` attribute to avoid name clashes.

### Local parameters

For a more understandable explanation, see the Zsh manual page about the [local parameters](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Local-Parameters).